# Exactly one line after @implementation and @interface with Uncrustify on Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, uncrustify

After the [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) pass, I would like this code block:

```
@implementation MyClass


- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
    }

    return self;
}
```

To look like:

```
@implementation VICameraOverlayViewController

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
    }

    return self;
}
```

Same goes for `@interface`

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController
- (void)initWithBlurSource:(id)blurSource;
@end
```

to

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController

- (void)initWithBlurSource:(id)blurSource;

@end
```

(Yeah there's an extra line before `@end` too)

Comment: I don't get your question, do you want to change the patterns or whats your intension?

Comment: Uncrustify should automatically convert the snippets into the expected snippets, maybe you should look what Uncrustify is all about... then my question will be very clear to you.

Comment: You could also insert a link to `Uncrustify` for all the people who don't know about it. This should be the right one https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode

Comment: Done, added the Source Forge link.

Comment: If you are interesting in exploring other options, consider Clang Format with MaxEmptyLinesToKeep = 1. Xcode plugin: https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode Standalone tool: Clang for Darwin 10.9 at http://llvm.org/releases/download.html